# Add new item to a list/partial view without reload the page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I did some googling, found this may need to use Partial View and JavaScript. But want to get some suggestions before I dig further.

What I am trying to achieve is:
Enter some text in a textbox, press a button, page does not get refreshed(using JavaScript), somewhere above or under the textbox it shows the text just typed(no saved in the database yet), and the ability to remove any added item(maybe with a x button after each piece of text, when click that piece of text is removed from the page, like how the tags is removed in stackoverflow).

Thank you.

Comment: If anyone could point me a sample which can do this kind of job would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a start. maybe someone else can finish it. I got to go

```js
var paragraphInput = document.querySelector('#paragraphInput');
var tagsHere = document.querySelector('#tagsHere');
document.querySelector('#breakBtn').addEventListener('click',function(){

  var words = paragraphInput.value.split(" ");
  console.log(words);
  
  for( var i = words.length; i>=0; i--){
    if( words[i] != undefined ){
  
      var newspan = document.createElement("span");
      newspan.classList = "post-tag";
      newspan.innerHTML = words[i] + "<span class='delete-tag'></span>";
      tagsHere.appendChild(newspan)
      }
  }
});
```

```css
html, body {
    font-family: Arial,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1.26666667;
    color: #242729;
}
.tag-editor {
    border: 1px solid #c8ccd0;
    cursor: text;
    background-color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div, span{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
.post-tag {
    
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: .4em .5em;
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 1;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 0;
    transition: all .15s ease-in-out;
    color: #39739d;
    background-color: #E1ECF4;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.delete-tag {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
    background-position: -40px -319px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=0786b22b9381);
    background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=1b3cdae197be),none;
    background-size: initial;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="paragraphInput"></textarea>
<input id="breakBtn" type="button" value="break" ></input>

<br><br>

<div class="tag-editor">


<span id="tagsHere">

<span class="post-tag rendered-element">javascript<span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span></span>

<span class="post-tag rendered-element">asp.net-core-mvc<span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span></span>

<span class="post-tag rendered-element">asp.net-mvc-partialview<span class="delete-tag" title="remove this tag"></span></span>

</span>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will have a try.

Answer (score 0):

Found a post which is using JQuery plugin tokenInput, does pretty much everything I need(still figuring out the style part). This example is for .net user:
https://medium.com/yasser-shaikh/using-jquery-tokeninput-with-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-f80c2d68e994

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything that you mentioned with straight HTML and jQuery.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mXVxXJ

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#listSection').on('click', '.itemDelete', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
  });
});


  function addItem() {
    var text = $('#txtVal').val(); 
    $('#listSection ul').append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + text + "<a href='#' title='Remove Item' class='itemDelete'> X</a></li>");
    $('#txtVal').val('');
  };
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Dynamic List Example</h3>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Enter Text</label>
        <input id="txtVal" type='text' class="form-control"></input><br/>
        <button id="AddButton" onClick="addItem()" class="btn btn-primary">Add to list</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <label>My List</label>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <div id="listSection">
          <ul class="list-group">
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```